How should I secure ceiling drywall with no edge backing?
I am trying to finish my garage and I am currently in the process of putting drywall. The issue that I am facing with the ceiling is that I do not have any framing at the edges to screw the sheet to.
The plan that I have in my mind is to try to detach the sheet and put it back in to make sure it does fit over the sheets on the side so that there is some support - however the garage has a 2% slope that might make all of this a little bit more complicated.
Has anybody ever encounter a similar situation? Are there any tools out there for these situations in particular?



Why isn't there any wood there to attach to? Was the wall added later as a renovation?

@Matthew, when walls are running parallel to joist or trusses it is planned that the drywall will be put on the ceiling first and the edges are resting on the top plate of the walls. Then the wall piece is jacked up to meet and support the ceiling piece.  Unless deadwood support is in place for the drywall attachment this is the standard method. Having deadwood added is not common and unlikely in most cases.

It's a myth that wall drywall supports ceiling drywall. That's unnecessary and not a good practice to rely upon. (If it was necessary, the edges of sheets away from the walls would be falling down.) It's not at all standard practice in the building industry short of production scenarios where corners are being cut.

It is not a myth, but a common practice in some areas of the country.  There is theory and real world practice.  Often when doing home reno, one comes upon real world practices.

You should have proper framing as backing and support. This early in the project there's no excuse for not doing this correctly. Simply resting the sheets on other drywall or a trim strip isn't adequate--a slamming door can create enough pressure to push the ends up, making noise and doing damage. Even if you were to glue the sheets to a face-mounted trim strip (which still may not hold), the same amount of effort can get you a professional-looking result instead of a patch job.
From what I can see, you have two options. The first step is the same for both:

Pull down any ceiling drywall spanning into the end joist cavity (for the first approach), or the final two cavities (for the second approach). Also remove the insulation from that area, or at least pull it back so you can work.

Run a ledger over the wall

Lay a two-by either against the next joist (over the wall), or on top of the wall plate. It should extend inside the wall face by at least an inch. Two is better. It should be on plane with the rest of the ceiling framing, so check with a straightedge. Don't trust that the wall plate is the right position. Secure it with nails or screws as you're able.

Run cross-blocking

Run 2x4 blocks between the last ceiling joist before the wall and the one over the wall, or to the wall plate itself. These should be on 24", 19.2",  or 16" centers corresponding to your existing drywall edges. Again, set the final ends on plane, not just on whatever framing happens to already be there. This is critical to avoid a wonky bend in your ceiling.


I generally agree with this for an interior project. However for a garage it is a lot of tearing out of what is already there.  Sometimes a hamburger is ok to curb your hunger, you don't need to eat a steak.

@RMDman If you can have good steak, why opting for McDonald's burger? Especially in garage, you dont wat to have (potentially) loose drywall above your car. If you aint having framing, make yourself the framing.

@Huesmann, are you referring to the wall? I didn't mention that. Also, it's probably a firewall and shouldn't be modified.

The usual method of hanging drywall would have the ceiling done first, then the walls. Then the wall pieces would give support to the ends of the ceiling boards.
You could try to put each piece in over the edge of the wall boards already done. That would obviously work. However it is time consuming and can be a challenge in some areas as you know. There are no special tool for this.
An alternative is to use 1 x 2s or firring strips along the edge of the walls to hold the ceiling board edges up.  It would not be the nicest look if in the interior, but this is a garage.   If the edges are caulked and then everything is painted it is not a bad finish and far easier than trying to tuck all the edges over the wall pieces.
Add the 1x2s along the upper edge of the sidewalls. As shown in the yellow.


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

it looks like the wall studs go up past the ceiling line so nail some 2x2 (or similar) timber to the studs horizontally in line with the top surface of the ceiling drywall
You can nail through the existing drywall into the studs if you want
Then you can fix the edge of your ceiling drywall to this.

If you can get the ceiling drywall close enough to the wall, then some trim mounted to the studs in the wall, can be positioned to hold the ceiling drywall in place.

Not the best solution, but certainly better than supporting wallboard only with more wallboard.
